# How can I compare each element of one string array to every element of another string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I've got two string arrays. I want to select one element from the first array and compare to each element of the second array. If element from first array exist in elements of second array i whant to write for example ("Element exist") or something like this.

This should be possible to do with two for loops ?

EDIT

Ok i finaly achived what i wanted usign this code:

```
string[] ArrayA = { "dog", "cat", "test", "ultra", "czkaka", "laka","kate" };
string[] ArrayB = { "what", "car", "test", "laka","laska","kate" };

bool foundSwith = false;

for (int i = 0; i < ArrayA.Length; i++)
{

   for (int j = 0; j < ArrayB.Length; j++)
   {
       if (ArrayA[i].Equals(ArrayB[j]))
       {
           foundSwith = true;
           Console.WriteLine("arrayA element: " + ArrayA[i] + " was FOUND in arrayB");
       }
   }

   if (foundSwith == false)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("arrayA element: " + ArrayA[i] + " was NOT found in arrayB");
   }
   foundSwith = false;
}
```

I hope this will help others who will want to compare two arrays ;). its all about this foundSwitch. Thx for help once again.

Comment: "This should be possible to do with two for loops ?" Absolutely! Did you try writing these two loops? How did it go?

Comment: It probably takes longer to write this post than to write a script to test this. #lazy

Comment: Sorry about not giving a code. I edited first post with my code.

Comment: You can replace `else if (s1 != s2)` with only `else`... and it will work fine... what is the problem then?

Comment: Could you check out my example in main question ? I just added to clarify what im trying to do. When im using else instead of else if i got the same wrong result (just like i write in example in main question)

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach (string str in yourFirstArray)
{
   if (yourSearchedArray.Contains(str))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Exists");
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but you should not create the List<> it creates a new copy of the array which is unnecessary overhead. You could just use yourStringArray.Contains(str) directly.

Comment: Im using .NET framework 2.0 and o got errors with this Even when i add using System.Linq.

Comment: can you try using 'Array.Exists()` instead of `Contains`? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be(v=vs.80))

Comment: i cannot unfortunately. Im trying to use code from belowe comment: foreach (string str in strArray)
{
   foreach (string str2 in strArray2)
   {
       if (str == str2)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("element exists");
       }else { Console.WriteLine ("element doesnt exists");
   }
} But i also need else statmant to write (this element does not exists). But when i write else stataments it overiterates i dont know why

Comment: can you update your code with the new version and explain the problem again?

Comment: I updated the code in above. Hope this will help you to help me ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string str in strArray)
{
   foreach (string str2 in strArray2)
   {
       if (str == str2)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("element exists");
       }
   }
}
```

*Updated to display when string does not exist in strArray2*

```
bool matchFound = false;
foreach (string str in strArray)
    {
       foreach (string str2 in strArray2)
       {
           if (str == str2)
           {
              matchFound = true;
              Console.WriteLine("a match has been found");
           }
       }

       if (matchFound == false)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("no match found");
       }
    }
```

Or another way of doing this in less lines of code:

```
foreach (string str in strArray)
{
    if(strArray2.Contains(str))
    {
       Console.WriteLine("a match has been found");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("no match found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Its good but when i add to this if  and else statmant for displaying this element not exist i receive weird result. Like its over iterating. How to add to this functionality - when element exists  it writes element exists but when not element does not exists  ?

Answer (score -1):

You can also try:

```
ArrayA.All(ArrayB.Contains);
```